# Finding the phase of a transfer function symbolically in python

Tags: python-2.7, symbolic-math, complex-numbers

I would like to find the phase of a transfer function in python symbolically

I would like for example to find the phase of H_lp1 given below

```
from sympy import *
import cmath

import numpy as np

fr = Symbol('fr', real=True)

fo = Symbol('fo', real=True)
fn = Symbol('fn', real=True)
f = Symbol('f',real=True)
q = Symbol('q', real=True)
qn = Symbol('qn', real=True)

wr = 2*pi*fr
wo = 2*pi*fo
wn = 2*pi*fn
w = 2*pi*f
s = I*w


H_lp1 = wo/(s+wo)
```

Thanks

Adding a more complicated example

## LPN - s domain

```
H_lpn2 = (s**2*(wo/wn)**2+wo**2)/(s**2+s*(wo/q)+wo**2)

(re_part,im_part) = H_lpn2.expand(complex=True).as_real_imag()

H_lpn2_ph_expanded = atan(im_part/re_part)

H_lpn2_ph = simplify(H_lpn2_ph_expanded)

produces atan(f*fo/(q*(f**2 - fo**2)))
```

This is incorrect as it dropped the term that contains the fn

The correct expression should be

```
pi*sign(f**2-fn**2)/2 -atan(q*(f**2-fo**2)/(f*fo))
```

Comment: How do I find the real and imaginary parts of such an expression as H_lp1?

Answer (score 0):

Normally is better to use Sympy own constants. I suppose that you expect fr and f to be real numbers, that would return a simpler expression. I would rewrite your example as:

```
from sympy import pi, Symbol, I, atan, im, re

# Defining the values as real numbers allows to simplify
# the resulting expression as im(fr) or re(fr)

fr = Symbol('fr', real=True)
f = Symbol('f', real=True)

wo = 2*pi*fr
w = 2*pi*f
s = I*w
H_lp1 = wo/(s+wo)
# The expresion has to be expanded first to have the I in the
# numerator
(re_part, im_part) = H_lp1.expand(complex=True).as_real_imag()
atan(im_part/ re_part)
```

That gives as an answer:

```
-atan(f/fr)
```

Or alternative you can also:

```
H_lp1 = H_lp1.expand(complex=True)
atan(im(H_lp1)/re(H_lp1))
```

With the same result

Comment: This is good and works for the case above. When I try a more complicated example along with simplify it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is correct:

`atan(f*fo/(q*(f**2 - fo**2)))`

the numerator of the expression is a real number so the angle is minus times the angle of the denominator and this is just:

`-atan(w*wo/(q*(wo**2 - w**2))`

equivalent to what you get from sympy!!.